# Talking or speaking to someone

Tags: phrases

What is the correct phrase to use?

> I am **speaking** on the phone? Please keep quiet for a while.

or

> I am **talking** on the phone? Please keep quiet for a while.

To me, the first one makes more sense.

Comment: Also consider simply “I’m on the phone”.

Answer (score 2):

Both are perfectly grammatically correct.

- I am speaking / talking on the phone. Please keep quiet for a while.

Also, to me, it sounds more natural to say "I am speaking *with someone* on the phone", rather than simply just "I am speaking on the phone". But perhaps that is just my personal preference.